# How to handle connection reset error in socket program

Tags: java, sockets, error-handling

I have written a program given below. It accept some data from client & returns success in response. Sometimes it throws connection reset error & due to which some socket connection remain unclose result. Any idea how to handle connection reset error when client code tries to communicate & connection is closed by client automatically?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class tcp_server implements Runnable {

    private final Socket server;
    private PrintWriter toClient = null;
    private BufferedReader fromClient = null;

    public tcp_server(Socket s) {
        this.server = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String name = "";
        synchronized (server) {
            try {
                server.setSoTimeout(6000);
                toClient
                        = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
                fromClient
                        = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                String data = "";
                while ((line = fromClient.readLine()) != null) {
                    data = data + line;
                    toClient.println("{status:success}");
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception eb) {

                System.out.println("{status:error,Reason:" + eb.getMessage() + "}");
            } finally {
                // System.out.println("Finally not called if timeout occurs");
                if (toClient != null) {                    
                    toClient.close();
                }
                if (fromClient != null) {
                    try {                        
                        fromClient.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(tcp_server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
                try {
                  server.close();                    
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(tcp_server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int serverPort = 40820;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
        synchronized (serverSocket) {
            for (;;) {
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
                new Thread(new tcp_server(server)).start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is better code ... but still with same error "Connection reset" though applied timeout to 60sec

Comment: What is the exact exception? (What line of code is it thrown from?) I remember having something similar and there wasn't much I could do about it. Basically, if a client disconnects before the server sends all of the data (think of someone pressing "stop" in a web browser half way through a request or something), this gets thrown and if I rememeber correctly, I am not sure that there is anything you can do to catch it

Comment: The error is at line " while ((line = fromClient.readLine()) != null) {"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *handle* it by closing the connection, of course.

The real question is why did you get it? There are several common causes:

- you wrote to a connection that had already been closed by the peer
- you closed a connection without reading data that had already arrived in the socket receive buffer. This will reset the peer.

Both of these are application protocol errors that should be fixed. There isn't any point in sending data that won't be read.

Comment: From above 2 points i only find 1st point valid. but  then if i writing to a connection that had already been closed ,after too many such cases , won't it give me "Too many open files error " in near future?

Comment: @Bhavesh None of that makes sense. Both are valid. Both of them may not apply to your current situation, but that isn't the same thing as 'validity'. The peer closing the connection doesn't have any bearing on running out of file descriptors at the local end, assuming you close connections that have failed as recommended here.